# Why do these 2 output styles give different answers

Tags: c++

So in c++ why are these 2 outputs different?

```
int x;
for(int x=2;x<5;x++);
cout<<x<< x++ << ++x << x <<endl;
```

this out outputs 7677

```
cout<<x<<endl;
cout<<x++<<endl;
cout<<++x<<endl;
cout<<x<<endl;
```

this out outputs 5577

so why are they different?

what i guessed is the first one computes the entire line at the same time that's why it outputs 7 but then why would `++x` still output 6? is there some kind of priority here or what is going on?

Comment: First, your `x` is not initialized in the first example.  The `x` in the loop is not the same as the one declared globally.

Comment: Because only one of them is well-defined, while the other one is undefined behavior (no sequence points, uninitialized `x` because of semicolon after the loop).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior-in-c applies to C++ here.

Comment: The first has undefined behaviour, which means any results are permitted,  since the two modifications of `x` are unsequenced.   Therefore, any behaviour is permitted, whether it makes sense to you or not.    The second has well defined behaviour.

Comment: How could this code compile, since you have `i` in the `for` loop, and not `x`?  Make sure that if you're going to show output for a block of code, copy and paste the *exact* code you're running -- don't hastily type in code into the edit window.

Comment: output will be well defined in c++17.

Comment: What is `i` in `for(int x=2;i<5;x++);`??? What is the purpose of this cycle with empty body?

Comment: Given that this question was asked at all, it is a pretty fair bet the OP is not using a C++17 compiler so the relevant standard predates C++17 - in which case the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be different in C++17, but not before it.

> In a shift operator expression `E1<<E2` and `E1>>E2`, every value computation and side-effect of E1 is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of E2 (since C++17)

If you use a C++ standard before C++17, then the behavior is [undefined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), so the complier can do any work you don't want.

If you want to learn more about in which context can a evaluation expression lead an Undefined Behavior, see this:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: Those aren’t shifts.

Comment: @ScottHunter Both built-in shift and overloaded shift adapt it.